# How to clone a rectangle along a line in Inkscape without any deformation?

Tags: inkscape

I'm trying to copy a rectangle along a line at regular spacing. From reading, I understood that I can leverage `Extensions/Generate from Path/Pattern along path (or scatter)` to do this. I tried both---pattern along path as well as scatter---without any success. How can I do this? Thanks.

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

My failed attempts:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Won't *Generate from path -> Interpolate* give a good approximation of what you need? You provide the first and last rectangles (converted to paths), and the extensions fills in the rest.

Comment: @Juancho It worked. Thanks.

Comment: @Juancho: You should transform your question to an answer, so that the question can show up as answered in all the overviews. Who will look for it, if there is no answer, not even an unaccepted non-upvoted one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way to produce a sequence of shapes is by using path interpolation (under *Extensions -> Generate from path -> Interpolate*.

Draw the first and last shapes (converted to paths), select both, and apply this extension to create the shapes in between.

Another option is to use tiled clones, carefully calculating the translation offsets.

Answer (score 1):

For those who prefer to use the Scatter extension (interpolate might modify the result, and it requires a path, not a rectangle):

[image: Stacked squares with Scatter extension]